# React JS element class names not rendering

Tags: reactjs

Working on a pre existing React JS project and the className attribute does not render in the DOM what is defined.

For example - here is what code looks like in the project:

```
<div className={styles.intro_inner}></div>
```

Here is the output in the DOM:

[image]

I'm expecting the class name "intro_inner" to appear within the DOM.

Comment: Module bundlers (like webpack) do that while bundling your app.

Comment: Webpack is not being used with this application - or - are you saying I should be using webpack to help with this issue?

Comment: Then what are you using to bundle your app?

Comment: Sorry - webpack is being used.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with webpack, I'll add an answer below....

Answer (score 1):

Within JSX, the syntax `attribute={variable}` on a component means that the attribute will be set with the ***value*** of the given variable, not it's name.  I would assume that your code has an object named `styles` which has an attribute named `intro_inner` whose value is some random mash of characters that you see output in the inspector.

If you want the class to be set as "intro_inner" then you need to set it as a string, not a variable.  The syntax for that would be `className="intro_inner"`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So would my classNames look something like this? <div className={"header" + styles.header_inner}> that looks a bit messy to me?

Comment: No.  It would just be `<div className="header">`.  The curly brackets signify taking the value from a variable.  If you just want to apply a static value, you just drop it in as a plain old string.  It's the same as typical javascript; `var variable = "some string"` versus `var variable = someOtherVariable`.

Comment: So the variable "styles" is being imported from "styles.css" to apply styling. I would expect webpack to convert the className and render along with the ID? My question is how do I get both working.

Comment: I think you're confusing CSS with JS.  CSS files do not create javascript variables.  CSS is it's own world, which html is able to interact with via class names.  React/JSX doesn't change this at all, aside from allowing more dynamic control over which class name is applied.  You're still setting a string to the class name, and allowing the raw html/css functionality to apply the styles automatically as it always would.